# Unable to install 'tm' R package in 3.3.3

Tags: r

Hi I'm trying to install `tm` package in R 3.3.3 on Redhat 6 but its failing with Rpoppler dependency and Rpoppler is failing with below error. I have refered various links but none solved the issue.

```
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("tm", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org/") :
  installation of package ‘Rpoppler’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("tm", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org/") :
  installation of package ‘tm’ had non-zero exit status
> install.packages("Rpoppler", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org/")
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/Rpoppler_0.1-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 38275 bytes (37 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 37 KB

* installing *source* package ‘Rpoppler’ ...
** package ‘Rpoppler’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking whether pkg-config knows about poppler-glib >= 0.18.0... no
configure: error: cannot determine poppler-glib compile/link flags
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rpoppler’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/Rpoppler’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpEljcC7/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rpoppler", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org/") :
  installation of package ‘Rpoppler’ had non-zero exit status
```

---

I have modified the version of poppler in /usr/lib64/pkgconfig an was able to bypass the error but am stuck with new error. Not sure if changing the metadata in pkgconfig is a good idea.

```
install.packages("Rpoppler",  repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org/")
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/Rpoppler_0.1-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 38275 bytes (37 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 37 KB

* installing *source* package ‘Rpoppler’ ...
** package ‘Rpoppler’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking whether pkg-config knows about poppler-glib >= 0.18.0... yes
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ -m64 accepts -g... yes
checking whether we can use setErrorFunction... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
config.status: creating src/config.h
** libs
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include   -pthread -I/usr/include/poppler/glib -I/usr/include/poppler -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c Rpoppler.c -o Rpoppler.o
Rpoppler.c: In function ‘Rpoppler_PDF_info’:
Rpoppler.c:108: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘poppler_document_get_title’
Rpoppler.c:108: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
Rpoppler.c:113: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘poppler_document_get_subject’
Rpoppler.c:113: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
Rpoppler.c:118: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘poppler_document_get_keywords’
Rpoppler.c:118: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
Rpoppler.c:123: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘poppler_document_get_author’
Rpoppler.c:123: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
Rpoppler.c:128: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘poppler_document_get_creator’
Rpoppler.c:128: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
Rpoppler.c:133: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘poppler_document_get_producer’
Rpoppler.c:133: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
Rpoppler.c:140: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘poppler_document_get_creation_date’
Rpoppler.c:145: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘poppler_document_get_modification_date’
Rpoppler.c:175: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘poppler_document_is_linearized’
Rpoppler.c:179: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘poppler_document_get_pdf_version_string’
Rpoppler.c:179: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
Rpoppler.c:184: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘poppler_document_get_metadata’
Rpoppler.c:184: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
Rpoppler.c:91: warning: unused variable ‘err’
Rpoppler.c: In function ‘Rpoppler_PDF_fonts’:
Rpoppler.c:207: warning: unused variable ‘i’
Rpoppler.c: In function ‘Rpoppler_PDF_text’:
Rpoppler.c:285: error: too few arguments to function ‘poppler_page_get_text’
make: *** [Rpoppler.o] Error 1
**ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rpoppler’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/Rpoppler’**

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmp6HYusM/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rpoppler", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org/") :
  installation of package ‘Rpoppler’ had non-zero exit status
```

---

Upon further debugging, I found that the configure file in Rpoppler_0.1-0.tar.gz is hardcoded to check for 0.18.0 version. I did change the value to 0.12.4 but it also resulted in same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the research, tm 0.7.3 has some compilation issues. Installing 0.7.1 did the trick. Which installed Rpoppler as well.

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you that `poppler-glib` is missing. You should be able to install this from the repositories via:

```
sudo yum install poppler-glib-devel
```

**Edit:** However, it seems that RHEL 6 only includes `poppler-glib-develop` version 0.12.4, while `Rpoppler` requires at least version 0.18.0. A quick search did not bring up any backports. Either you compile your own backport or upgrade the OS. RHEL 7 should be sufficient.

Comment: > poppler-glib-devel is installed already. Name        : poppler-glib-devel
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 0.12.4
Release     : 12.el6_9
Size        : 514
Repo        : installed
From repo   : rhel-6-server-optional-rpms
Summary     : Development files for glib wrapper
URL         : http://poppler.freedesktop.org/
License     : GPLv2
Description : Development files for glib wrapper.

Comment: @RajeshReddyB what's the output of `rpm -q poppler-glib-devel` and `pkg-config --modversion poppler-glib`?

Comment: Hi @Ralf Stubner, 

rpm -q poppler-glib-devel
poppler-glib-devel-0.12.4-12.el6_9.x86_64
 pkg-config --modversion poppler-glib
0.12.4

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this on OSX, here is a workflow I found.  As per https://github.com/cran/Rpoppler/blob/819bc04dd113f3ec12d8f7d8eecfab79569478d6/configure#L1830, we can see

### Install Poppler

`brew install poppler`

### Get the configuration

Try to run this.

`pkg-config --libs poppler-glib
pkg-config --cflags poppler-glib`

If you get something like `Package 'poppler-glib' requires 'glib-2.0 >= 2.41' but version of glib-2.0 is 2.36.0`, then you may need to change the order of `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`:

`echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

### Install New `glib`

`brew install glib`

Get the information of where it is installed for the updated one:

`brew info glib`

Find where glib is: (e.g.) `/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.58.1 (435 files, 18.4MB)`, make sure the number is high enough (e.g. 2.58).  Then add `lib/pkgconfig`.  We can automate this:

`` glib_path=`brew info glib | grep Cellar | awk '{print $1 }' | tail -n 1`
glib_path="${glib_path}/lib/pkgconfig"
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${glib_path}":"${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}"
pkg-config --libs poppler-glib ``

If that works, then try in `R`:

`install.packages("Rpoppler")`